# How to make a battery powered device work direct on power

Tags: sound-system, battery

I have an audio device that works with battery, but this little friend here stopped working,in fact it still works, but apparently it is sending a lot less energy than it should, nor being able to turn on the LED that indicates it is charging.
[image: Connector to charger]

Then I open this and found that battery
[image: Batery]

That goes here on the chip

[image]

I don't have much knowledge about electronics other than the basics, I can identify some things on the device, but not enough, someone could tell me how to get me to send power to the device without needing the battery or the connector to charge

Comment: If you'd like us to help you find the power cord/plug for that TRC-219 , just let us know the brand or manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for ways to control the voltage of an outlet, since we are in quarantine, I would not find resistors and transistors. But I just remembered that USB cables already do this job for me. As I have several unused at home, I stripped one, stuck the negative and positive of those that were connected to the battery and it is working perfectly. I was even able to use one of the screw holes to make the wire exit.
[image]

Ah, it seems that I touched some circuit of the led monitor, now it is not correctly positioned, but a minimal damage for having it working again